# Ajax doesn't load PHP scripts over https

Tags: jquery, ajax, ssl, https

I have added SSL to my website at any page through Let's Encrypt. Before, everything worked just fine but after I've added this, the ajax scripts do fire off and the console says it's successfully loaded, but it doesn't load any content from the actual PHP files. When I try to achieve the loading through http request, it tells me, that it's failed loading. I have tried to set `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.meetotakus.net"` in my .htaccess file, but that doesn't work. Is there any solution for this? I am kinda desperate.

Answer (score 0):

Please add

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/assets/php/ajax/processor\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

in .htaccess. It supports https ajax call.

Comment: I've put it on top of my .htaccess file but that neither seems to work unfortunately

Comment: Alright I've set Rewriting Rules for my .php files in my .htaccess file. Now it works!